# How to apply an NSPredicate to a custom XLForm row?

Tags: xlform

I have a row of type `XLFormRowDescriptionTypeSelectorPush`

I set `row.value` to a custom class `Agreement` and `row.addValidator(AgreementValidator())`

I want another to be hidden/shown depending upon the value of Agreement.agree (which is `"Accepted"` or `"Declined"`).

I can't figure out how to do this. Here's where I am so far:

```
other_row.hidden = NSPredicate(format:"$other_tag.value != "Accepted")
```

But the value of the other_tag row is `Agreement` and not a string. How can I compare with `Agreement.agree`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
other_row.hidden = NSPredicate(format: "NOT $other_tag.value.agree != 'Accepted'")
```

Comment: Glad that it helped you :)